# Django 2.2 default login url

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I want to load the Django builtin login page, but not with the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/, instead of this i am trying to load the login page like this URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/

I have tried :

```
LOGIN_URL ='/login/' - (in settings.py)
@login_required()- (in the app view.py)
@login_required(login_url='/login/')  - (in the app view.py)
```

these both method not helped me, kindly someone help me to sort this out.

project url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),       
    path('',include('home.urls')),
]
```

project settings.py in the bottom i have included like below

```
LOGIN_URL='/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL ='home'
```

in my app url

#

```
from django.urls import path, include
from home.views import HomeView
urlpatterns = [     
    path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('home',HomeView, name='home'),
]
```

in app view.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

@login_required(login_url='/login/') 
def HomeView(request): 
  return render(request, "home.html")
```

overall my expectation to load the Django default Login page without passing /login/ or account/login in the url.

Comment: I don't understand; if you want the login page at / and not /login/, why have you set LOGIN_URL to /login/?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i just tried to access the login page which is working perfectly when i pass the /login/ in the url, so i tried to set the default URL.

Comment: This is too confusing. If you want the login URL to be "/", why don't you set LOGIN_URL to "/"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman if i set the LOGIN_URL="/", weather it will redirect to the login page which is ultimately i needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a generic class

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
  path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin/'), name='django_admin'),
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('other/', include('other.urls')),
]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/

Comment: thanks for your reply, your solution worked to get the django admin login page, but i am trying to generate from the Front end something like this.  path('',RedirectView.as_view(url='/login/'), include('django.contrib.auth.urls')), i know its not the right way to call the django login page like this. kindly help

Comment: Finally solved, i have created username and password field separately in login.html field instead of {{ form.as_p }}. thanks all for the support. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try change `'/login/'` for `''` in all files.